# how to ignore the certain models generated in swagger ui schemas section

Tags: c#, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

I have .net solution with multiple projects and some of them have controllers in it.
I found a way to generate the endpoints with only desired route (ex: `swaggerDoc.Paths.Contains("someapi/")`) to limit exposing the controllers from all different assemblies using custom implementation of IDocumentFilter `services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {c.DocumentFilter<SwaggerFilters>();}`.

The problem is the schema section generates the models for all the assemblies in the solution and have to retain only the schema for the exposed endpoints in the swagger ui.

```
public class SwaggerDocFilters : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        var nonMobileRoutes = swaggerDoc.Paths
                        .Where(x => !x.Key.ToLower().Contains("someRoute/"))
                        .ToList();

        nonMobileRoutes.ForEach(x => { swaggerDoc.Paths.Remove(x.Key); });

        foreach (var item in swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Where(x => !x.Key.Contains("SomeModel")))
        {
            swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Remove(item.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

With above approach It turns out I must know all the models name to generate the schema.

Is there a better way to expose only controllers (endpoints and schemas) from a selected assembly ?

Comment: I mark all filtered actions with `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]`. I don't know if there's a good way to apply a global filter.

Comment: Rather than filtering the swagger documentation, I think you should filter the application model as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/application-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0#modify-the-applicationmodel and set the visibility as per https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/e5c96485cf22863032f72ef036e5f61799fa8883/src/Mvc/test/WebSites/ApiExplorerWebSite/ApiExplorerVisibilityEnabledConvention.cs#L14